# Ambiguous Netbeans error when including Google's contracts for java (cofoja)

Tags: netbeans

I am using Netbeans 8.0 and want to import a third-party library including an annotation processor. To be specific, it is Google's contracts for java, but I am not sure if that matters.
I included the library and configured the annotation processor under the project's properties.

Now, when I add the library to the project, for the import line of the package, Netbeans does not give an error, however, when I want to use the package (@Requires(...)), it tells me:

```
error in contract: package com.google.java.contract does not exist
```

Is that a problem that occurs more often with Netbeans or should I suspect that it is specific to the library I am trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702652/cofoja-error-error-in-contract-package-com-google-java-contract-does-not-exi) for the solution. You will need to pass in the classpath, sourcepath and classoutput as compilerargs

Go to project properties -> Build -> compiling and in the Processor options add in

```
     com.google.java.contract.classpath
     com.google.java.contract.sourcepath
     com.google.java.contract.classoutput
```

Regards